# How to load different Header In Wordpress Woocomerce my account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am unable to load different header in my website where i am using login functionality from woocomerce plugin. I need to load different header for my account page i.e, login, lost password, registration page. I need to call template part for css and js files instead of loading header

Comment: Hello ,

add a condition in header.php

if(is_front_page())
{
    get_header('home');
}
else
{
    get_header();
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this.

```
if(is_account_page()){
    //load your custom header
}else{
    get_header();
}
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/